# Someone is eating my errors, how can I debug it?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, rxjs, superagent

I'm writing a react application using [Router1](https://github.com/zxbodya/router1). Here is how the final subscription looks like:

```js
router
  .renderResult()
  .forEach(() => {
    window.ga('send', 'pageview', window.location.pathname);
  });
```

This stream throwing an error (unhandled error), but I don't see it in the console. If I put onError callback in `forEach` - I can log errors.

If I fix error in stream and create another stream inside, that throws an error, I don't see the message in console:

```js
router
  .renderResult()
  .forEach(() => {
    window.ga('send', 'pageview', window.location.pathname);
    Observable.throw(1).subscribe();
  });
```

And even if I replace `Observable.throw(1).subscribe();` with simple `throw 1` - result is the same, no messages in console and stream is broken.

But If I fix error in the stream, and create another stream that throws an error after some timeout, I see the message "rx.all.js:77 Uncaught 1" which is great.

```js
router
  .renderResult()
  .forEach(() => {
    window.ga('send', 'pageview', window.location.pathname);
    setTimeout(() => Observable.throw(1).subscribe(), 1000);
  });
```

So by default rx throws unhandled exceptions, but not in this case, why? Who eating my errors? Any ideas how can I debug it?

Comment: Running in Firefox?

Comment: @trincot no, Chrome. Actually in any browser (Chrome, Firefox, Safari) behaviour is the same. Is there something special about Firefox?

Comment: om nom nom nom... eating all your tasty errors :P

Comment: Well, in FireFox some errors only show in the window that opens with `Ctrl+J` (which shows errors from all windows). Probably not the issue here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've found who was eating my tasty errors - superagent@2.0.0. [Issue is already fixed](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/issues/1000) and will be released in the next version.

Here is example how you can feed errors to superagent:

```
import { Observable } from 'rx';
import superagent from 'superagent';

const request = superagent.get('/');
Observable.defer(
  Observable.fromNodeCallback(request.end, request, res => res.body)
).subscribe(() => { 
  throw new Error('tasty error');
});
```